# Matplotlib: is it possible to do a stepwise stacked plot?

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to make a [stacked area chart](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/stacked-area-plot/) but it would increase stepwise, like the [stairs plot](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html).

It is a cumulative chart, so a stepwise increase would make more sense.

How can it be done?

Comment: maybe you could use a `stairs` plot with setting the `baseline` as shown in the middle example of the stairs demo you linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`plt.stackplot`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot.html) accepts extra kwargs which are sent to [`plt.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between). One of those is `step='post'`, creating a horizontal line starting with the given value. (In contrast, `step='pre'` has the horizontal lines at the height of the ending positions.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 6)
y1 = np.random.rand(5) + 1
y2 = np.random.rand(5) + 2
y3 = np.random.rand(5) + 3

plt.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, step='post', labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
plt.xticks(x)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.stackplot with step function]