# matplotlib skips final bin contents when using stackplot and option "step=post"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When using the matplotlib "stackplot" function to make a stacked histogram plot, the recommended usage is to set the option "step=post", creating the following output code from

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904252/matplotlib-is-it-possible-to-do-a-stepwise-stacked-plot)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 6)
y1 = np.random.rand(5) + 1
y2 = np.random.rand(5) + 2
y3 = np.random.rand(5) + 3

plt.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, step='post', labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
plt.xticks(x)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: output stackplot from code above]

However, you'll notice y1,y2,y3 has 5 entries, but only 4 were plotted because "x" apparently defines bin edges in this configuration of stackplot. So, the last values of y1, y2, y3 aren't plotted!

```
>>> print(x)
[1 2 3 4 5]
>>> print(y1)
[1.71646043 1.23771272 1.65941422 1.72969164 1.52808725]
>>> print(y2)
[2.40110752 2.27181556 2.79389289 2.36282173 2.17705337]
>>> print(y3)
[3.19368033 3.75562859 3.52841431 3.74812933 3.89716171]
```

What is the best way get those final bins of y1, y2, y3 on the same plot?

So far, I am using this little hack, which produces the expected output, but I don't like it because it adds zeros to y1, y2, y3, which I might want to use again later after plotting. I could easily remove them after plotting, but it begs the question of intended usage of this function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 6)
y1 = np.random.rand(5) + 1
y2 = np.random.rand(5) + 2
y3 = np.random.rand(5) + 3

x = np.append(x, 6) # np.arange above does not include the final value
y1 = np.append(y1, 0)
y2 = np.append(y2, 0)
y3 = np.append(y3, 0)

plt.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, step='post', labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
plt.xticks(x)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: correct output]

Does someone know of a way to use stackplot so that it gives the expected output without altering the input data (x, y1, y2, y3) ?

P.S. sorry if this shouldn't be it's own post. I didn't have enough reputation to comment on the original, but this seems like a big oversight if you're expecting to plot all of your data with these setting, especially if you have a setup where your final bins should contain overflows (or underflows in the case of "step=pre").

Comment: The `x` aren't considered bins. `stackplot` is similar to `plot`, but with coloring inbetween. Now, here you aren't using a standard line plot, but a "step" plot. The only way to have a step plot look like there is also a last step (using `step='post' : the step starts after the xy value), is by adding extra elements, as you just did. The reason this isn't included in the standard functionality is probably that often the extra step isn't desired.